# Why is a brutal 3 vorpal scythe called "Death's Scythe"?

Tags: dnd-4e

The title is essentially my question.  I have heard the weapon called that before, but i am curious as to both the why, and as to the origin of this term and the concept of the weapon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A Scythe is a 2d4 damage weapon.

A brutal weapon asks you to reroll damage dice that are equal or lower in number to the weapon's brutal rating.

So a Brutal 3 Scythe automatically deals 8 damage on a hit. (As each d4 is rerolled until a 4 appears)

Make it Vorpal (L30 enchantment)

> Whenever you roll the maximum result on any damage die for this weapon, roll that die again and add the additional result to the damage total. If a reroll results in another maximum damage result, roll it again and keep adding

And your Brutal 3 Vorpal Scythe does infinite damage on every hit.

So every hit is an auto kill (barring any defensive funkyness) and so is a weapon worth of being weilded by Death

Comment: Is there such a thing as a Brutal 3 Scythe?

Comment: I know how to make a Brutal 1: Have a Battle Engineer ally (Any weapon buff make that weapon brutal 1), or use Bands of Equilibrium (daily power, Dragon 396). Unfortunately, they don't stack.